# Software Engineer Levels

Tags: software-industry, position

My company levels seem a little weird. Is it only me that thinks they are a little weird?

These are the individual contributor levels.
Associate Software Engineer -> Staff Software Engineer-> software Engineer -> Senior Engineer -> Lead Software Engineer.

What is a normal structure at most companies? It seems like staff would be higher than senior.

Is Lead Software engineer like a principal or tech lead?

Comment: That sounds pretty normal.  What about that seems weird to you, and what kind of answer are you looking for?  I suspect this will be closed as it isn't really the kind of question that can be answered in a useful way.

Comment: At most companies I've seen, "staff" is in between "senior" and "lead/principal". Source: I am currently a staff engineer after being promoted from senior. Have not made it to principal yet. But every company is different and titles aren't as important as what you actually do.

Comment: @thursdaysgeek I think they're looking for an explanation of what the different titles mean as far as how high up they are/experience/responsibility. Like Seth, I've more often seen "Staff" be used to indicate someone above "Senior". The problem is that "Staff" is not at all intuitive for the name of a level because staff is just a synonym for employee. (That and apparently it isn't even used in a consistent way.)

Comment: https://www.levels.fyi/

Comment: Every company does things differently (sometimes differences are small, sometimes they are huge), culture and company history can also have a big influence. You just need to know what things mean at your company.

Comment: While titles _can_ be standard in an industry, it's not always the case, and is generally up to the discretion of the hiring company. As usch, I'm going to Vote To Close on the basis that company-specific policies are off-topic for this stack.

Comment: Titles are not standard in the industry.  In particular, I've seen that canadian companies think staff is a fairly low level, whereas US places that use it place it at a high level.  All in all, I'd suggest ignoring levels and just focusing on if you're making the money you want.  Levels rarely actually effect anything once you're in a tech company.  I only know the level of one teammate of mine, and that's because I was asked to comment on his promotion.

Answer (score 1):

From what I've seen, the "staff" level for a software engineer is typically higher than a "senior", but not as high as a "lead" or "principal". So a more common progression at a company that even uses these titles would be:

Associate Engineer ->
Engineer ->
Senior Engineer ->
Staff Engineer ->
Lead/Principal Engineer

I was hired at my current company as a Senior Software Engineer and was later promoted to Staff. The Principal Engineers at my company carry broader responsibilities and typically have more experience than me.

In any job posting I've looked at for a Staff Engineer role, they require more experience and knowledge than similar roles with the Senior title.

So the progression at your company is somewhat atypical. But job titles are mostly meaningless anyway, and any company looking to hire you is going to pay more attention to what you've actually done than what titles you've held in the past.

Comment: I feel like these titles are putting me behind because they don't seem to line up with most of the industry.

Comment: @JTSmith, like I said, titles don't mean much when you get outside your company. Everyone measures it differently A staff engineer at one company could actually be less qualified than a senior at another. And some companies don't even use those titles at all. Future potential employers know this and will be much more interested in what experience you have than what your exact job title is. Concentrate on building your experience and you'll be fine.

Answer (score 1):

Although the levels that your company has are unusual for an engineer, they aren't that unusual in other fields. For example, a "staff accountant" is an entry-level or mid-level accounting position.

I also find it a bit unusual that "lead software engineer" is in the track of individual contributor roles.

In my experience, the common flow in technology-oriented or engineering-oriented organizations is associate engineer -> engineer -> senior engineer -> staff engineer -> principal engineer. A lead engineer is a senior (but more often a staff or principal) engineer who is overseeing the work of others and may or may not have direct managerial responsibilities. Some organizations may have more levels (often by numbering them, such as senior engineer 1, senior engineer 2), dropping some levels (such as making engineer the entry-level position), or both.

Comment: Lead being an IC role is VERY common.  Lead means that you're not a manager, but you're technically in charge of a project or feature.  It may be a level, or it may just be a job responsibility and not part of your HR title.  It's usually used at companies that don't expect all ICs to want to become manager.  I'd be surprised to see it anywhere other than an IC track.

Comment: I'd also say your normal flow has many more levels than most places I've seen.  And staff, if it exists, changes from being above senior to being below based on location (Canadian companies rate it high, most US companies that use it (a minority) rate it low).

Comment: @GabeSechan My list is a combination of what I've seen put into a single sequence. Most organizations don't have that many - I've seen 1 that went all the way with all of those levels and numbers in the middle for more granular pay bands. As far as the lead goes, I've rarely seen that as a level. The team's lead would have a title and payband of Senior Software Engineer, Staff Software Engineer, or Principal Software Engineer. They may even be a lead temporarily and then go back to not being a lead later without any changes in title or pay.